# routeProvider otherwise redirectTo not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I'm learning AngularJS with the book "Pro AngularJS" and I'm still a beginner. I've been stuck with this problem for a little while and found nothing to fix it yet.

I have a problem with redirecting in routeProvider. The problem is that the user should be redirected automatically after launching this page to another one (which you'll see in code below) and after launching it, nothing happens. It changes the link to http://localhost:50395/angularjs/admin.html#/login, but launches a blank white page.

Script in admin.html:

```
<script>
    angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when("/login", {
                templateUrl: "/views/adminLogin.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/main", {
                templateUrl: "/views/adminMain.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/login"
            });
        });
</script>
```

If someone could help me and get me clear on what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What errors are shown in the browser console?

Comment: 20:55:43.920 "Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /views/adminLogin.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: Have you created the `adminLogin.html` file and added it to the `views` directory?

Comment: Yup. It exists and is in /views directory. It contains two inputs for the user to put login and password in them.

Comment: Have you tried changing /views to just views? What is your project structure?

Comment: Changing "/views" to "views" worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dariel I'm glad I could help, please consider marking my answer as correct.

Comment: Done. Accepted as an correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove first slash from the path, for example:

`/views/..` so you have `views/..`